# Upload de imagem via forms com Django-StdImage

Tags: django

Estou tentando fazer upload de imagem via `forms` e `CreateView`, poŕém só consigo através do admin do Django. Estou utilizando `StdImage`.
Todos os dados são cadastrados normalmente no banco de dados com exceção da imagem.
Tem alguma forma de subir a imagem dessa forma?

***models.py:***

```
class Pub(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=RATING, blank=False, default="-")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bar")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = StdImageField(upload_to='static/img/', variations={'thumbnail': {"width": 300, "height": 400, "crop": True}}, blank=True, null=True)
```

***views.py:***

```
class PubCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Pub
    form_class = PubForm
    success_url = "/pubs/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(PubCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

***forms.py:***

```
class PubForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pub
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'rate', 'image']
```

***html:***

```
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit">enviar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: como esta o settings.py e urls.py configurado para receber a img ?

Comment: @stack.cardoso O _settings.py_ com `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`e _urls.py__ com `+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`. A imagem está sendo salva quando cadastro pelo /admin do django, apenas pelo html (form) que não subia. Alterei para utilizar **models.ImageField** e está funcionando via html, Manterei assim por enquanto.

Comment: Ha versão do dj que não possui mais os.path mas sim Path.join (BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: @stack.cardoso agradecço a ajuda! O problema estava no html. Não coloquei `enctype="multipart/form-data"` na tag <form>. Após incluir passou a funcionar normal.

Comment: disponha. Sucesso para teu projeto :)

Answer (score 0):

**Resolvido**

O problema estava no arquivo **html**. Por se tratar de upload de arquivo, deve colocar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` na tag `<form>`. Ou seja, o arquivo html ficou dessa forma:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit">enviar</button>
    </form>
```

Após isso as imagens passaram a ser salvas no banco de dados normalmente.